# How can I share my internet connection?

Tags: internet, sharing

I am trying to share my internet (LAN) connection using an ad-hoc WiFi network, but my iPod cannot see it.

I have "Method: shared to other computers" set up in IPv4 in the eth0 window and "Method: DHCP" in IPv4 in the wlan0 tab.

Why isn't my iPod able to see this network?